# Black tile on taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I have a black tile on the taskbar.  It will not run anything and I have not been able to remove it.  It says it is for Hulu when I right click on it, but I do have another Hulu shortcut on the taskbar that works.  The two items in the context menu are "Hulu" and "Pin to taskbar".  Clicking either one does nothing.  What I really want to do is remove it.  I have piddled around on my own.  There is no shortcut in the directory associated with those tiles, and the reg key has a ton of stuff that is in binary.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can go about removing it?

Adding screenshots: 
[image: Screenshot of blank tile] 
[image: Context menu]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @LPChip - Thank you for the reply.  Screenshots have been added to the original post.

Comment: Hulu is an app from the Microsoft Store, correct? If so, try to go to Settings->Apps->Hulu and delete its cache, similar on how you would do on a phone. This should act as a reinstall and may fix this stuck icon on your taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are prepared to uninstall & reinstall Hulu, then that's possibility. The downside is that you *may* have to reconfigure  it again (or maybe not).

I can't recommend [Revo uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) enough (the link is to the free version). I have been using it for 10 years or more, paid for the pro version, and can't find anything better, although I regularly look for alternatives to my staple apps every few months.

It will run the normal uninstall, then scan hard-drives and registry for any leftover traces, one of which is causing your artefact.

Comment: This makes me feel silly. As you recommended, I uninstalled the application and that got rid of it.  I don't know why I didn't think of that myself.  Thank you to everyone who chimed in to help!

Comment: Don't feel silly. Sometimes I have a blindspot - and that's when Stack Exchange helps me :-)  Just glad to have solved it